# Inserting long tables to a document

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am new to LaTeX and I am currently facing a problem of inserting long tables to a document.

[image]

I have a long table `.csv` and I wish to insert it in the document with multiple columns and a single table Header and caption like the image above.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pgfplotstable.data.csv}
Station,Lat,Lon,dg
1,-3.36867,36.625,-3.073
2,-2.41667,34.82917,12.68
3,-2.65833,31.3805,17.198
4,-1.32083,31.8195,-15.783
5,-6.825,39.28883,0.23
6,-6.835,39.26667,4.181
7,-6.82167,39.29633,0.722
8,-6.87633,39.20417,10.3
9,-6.87633,39.20333,3.298
10,-6.81917,39.28583,-0.891
11,-6.82167,39.29633,0.832
12,-6.855,39.28,4.102
13,-6.8,39.28333,-0.802
14,-6.82083,39.2875,-0.976
15,-6.16667,35.74583,-7.897
16,-2.87217,32.16383,-1.286
17,-7.875,32.48333,-36.034
18,-7.66117,35.76383,33.337
19,-4.56667,30.1,6.455
20,-1.77217,30.84333,-7.361
21,-4.87833,29.66667,-30.593
22,-8.775,39.40833,11.588
23,-8.912,39.51167,2.149
24,-4.89583,35.76833,1.135
25,-6.16667,36.42417,-7.367
26,-2.0625,35.54167,52.271
27,-10.74,38.76617,-15.588
28,-8.89167,33.44167,35.769
29,-8.91383,33.4555,35.369
30,-6.82117,37.65133,-15.818
31,-3.355,37.33,-38.447
32,-6.35433,31.07715,-14.84
33,-10.25,40.1,29.713
34,-2.42883,32.93133,-19.348
35,-9.3545,34.77083,103.94
36,-6.71667,32.06883,14.056
37,-3.40967,35.6125,-8.271
38,-8.34433,35.3055,61.539
39,-4.26667,34.18333,-31.827
40,-3.61667,33.5005,-42.218
41,-4.80967,34.7235,11.81
42,-10.67917,35.57367,21.493
43,-10.67917,35.5735,21.553
44,-7.94633,31.60883,98.383
45,-7.94633,31.60883,98.373
46,-5.07217,32.83617,-33.351
47,-5.08333,32.83333,-38.775
48,-5.07217,32.83617,-33.351
49,-5.0875,39.0695,-28.979
50,-5.1,39.06667,-24.826
51,-5.0875,39.0695,-28.949
52,-11.10133,37.36917,-23.768
53,-11.10133,37.36917,-23.688
54,-5.08933,30.40533,-18.289
55,-6.21667,39.21667,12.413
56,-6.21667,39.21667,12.443
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}
%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={Station,Lat,Lon,dg,Station,Lat,Lon,dg,Station,Lat,Lon,dg},
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘dg’
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘dg’
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘dg'
]{pgfplotstable.data.csv}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the code I get an error message:

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'Station' from table
> 'pgfplotstable.data.csv'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..

Where am I messing up?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You must add `col sep=comma`

Comment: Where on the latex code should I add that option?

Comment: Like this `\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,`

Comment: Thank you, it has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify that the column separator is the `comma`, pgfplots defaults to the `space` character. Therefore, it can't read your table.

Just specify that it is the comma : `col sep=comma,`

**I'm quoting from the page 5 of `pgfplotstable` manual:**

> ```
> /pgfplots/table/col sep=space|tab|comma|semicolon|colon|braces|&|ampersand (initially space)
> ```
>
> Specifies the column separation character for table reading.
> The initial choice, space, means “at least one white space”. White
> spaces are tab stops or spaces (newlines characters always delimit
> lines).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pgfplotstable.data.csv}
Station,Lat,Lon,dg
1,-3.36867,36.625,-3.073
2,-2.41667,34.82917,12.68
3,-2.65833,31.3805,17.198
4,-1.32083,31.8195,-15.783
5,-6.825,39.28883,0.23
6,-6.835,39.26667,4.181
7,-6.82167,39.29633,0.722
8,-6.87633,39.20417,10.3
9,-6.87633,39.20333,3.298
10,-6.81917,39.28583,-0.891
11,-6.82167,39.29633,0.832
12,-6.855,39.28,4.102
13,-6.8,39.28333,-0.802
14,-6.82083,39.2875,-0.976
15,-6.16667,35.74583,-7.897
16,-2.87217,32.16383,-1.286
17,-7.875,32.48333,-36.034
18,-7.66117,35.76383,33.337
19,-4.56667,30.1,6.455
20,-1.77217,30.84333,-7.361
21,-4.87833,29.66667,-30.593
22,-8.775,39.40833,11.588
23,-8.912,39.51167,2.149
24,-4.89583,35.76833,1.135
25,-6.16667,36.42417,-7.367
26,-2.0625,35.54167,52.271
27,-10.74,38.76617,-15.588
28,-8.89167,33.44167,35.769
29,-8.91383,33.4555,35.369
30,-6.82117,37.65133,-15.818
31,-3.355,37.33,-38.447
32,-6.35433,31.07715,-14.84
33,-10.25,40.1,29.713
34,-2.42883,32.93133,-19.348
35,-9.3545,34.77083,103.94
36,-6.71667,32.06883,14.056
37,-3.40967,35.6125,-8.271
38,-8.34433,35.3055,61.539
39,-4.26667,34.18333,-31.827
40,-3.61667,33.5005,-42.218
41,-4.80967,34.7235,11.81
42,-10.67917,35.57367,21.493
43,-10.67917,35.5735,21.553
44,-7.94633,31.60883,98.383
45,-7.94633,31.60883,98.373
46,-5.07217,32.83617,-33.351
47,-5.08333,32.83333,-38.775
48,-5.07217,32.83617,-33.351
49,-5.0875,39.0695,-28.979
50,-5.1,39.06667,-24.826
51,-5.0875,39.0695,-28.949
52,-11.10133,37.36917,-23.768
53,-11.10133,37.36917,-23.688
54,-5.08933,30.40533,-18.289
55,-6.21667,39.21667,12.413
56,-6.21667,39.21667,12.443
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}
%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,% <-- specifies that the comma is the column separator
columns={Station,Lat,Lon,dg,Station,Lat,Lon,dg,Station,Lat,Lon,dg},
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{3},string type},% first part of ‘dg’
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{3},string type},% Second part of ‘dg’
display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘station’
display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘lat’
display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘lon’
display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{3},string type},% Third part of ‘dg'
]{pgfplotstable.data.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How surprising that a *comma* separated file is actually separated by commas.